# Android RecyclerView GridLayoutManager Talkback Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to improve accessibility of one screen which is using recyclerview with gridlayout manager.

The span size of the gridlayoutmanager is 3. Depending on the backend response, sometimes i have 2 or 1 item in list. The issue which i have faced is that the talkback is announcing like that

> "item info 2, 2 of 3, in list, 3 items"

But actually i have only 2 items in the my list. I think talkback makes the calculation of item numbers according to span size. But it is misleading. Is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check source code of `GridLayoutManager#onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem# and see how it provide description for its item. See [AccessibilityNodeInfo.CollectionItemInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.CollectionItemInfo).

Comment: How can i overwrite it?